# How to assemble an SBT Scala library to be included in a Java 7 Maven project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, sbt

I'm having trouble building a Scala library through ***sbt-assembly*** such that it's able to be incorporated into a Java Maven project.  I have been successful in importing my Scala library into another Scala SBT project, however, so it at least seems to be a valid JVM binary from the viewpoint of Scala/SBT.

When I package my Scala library, I use the command `sbt assembly` and then I publish it locally via:

```
╰─$ mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=/full/path/to/develop/hello/test-library/target/scala-2.11/test-library-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-DgroupId="com.example" \
-DartifactId="test-library" \
-Dversion="0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" \
-DgeneratePom=true \
-Dpackaging=jar
```

The error message I'm seeing when I try to use the library from Java is the following:

(After packaging via `mvn clean package` where ***mvn is version 3.3.9***)

```
╰─$ java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: example/hello/Hello
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.hello.Hello
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

---

My Scala project looks like the following:

**build.sbt**

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.11",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
      scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"
    )),
    name := "test-library",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

**project/assembly.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

**src/main/scala/example/hello/Hello.scala**

```
package example.hello

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello!!!")
  }
}
```

---

The Java Project is as follows

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-library</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java**

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import example.hello.*;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App //extends URLClassLoader
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Hello.main(null);
    }
}
```

---

**Does the library get installed under `test-library_2.11`?**

No, it does not.  Here is the relevant output from the `mvn install:install-file` command.

```
[INFO] Installing /full/path/to/develop/hello/test-library/target/scala-2.11/test-library-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/<my-name>/.m2/repository/com/example/test-library/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-library-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /tmp/mvninstall9208544268925838468.pom to /home/<my-name>/.m2/repository/com/example/test-library/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-library-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Comment: Check your local maven/ivy cache - `artifactId` will most likely be sth like `test-library_2.11`.

Comment: That doesn't look like the case, here: `[INFO] Installing /full/path/to/develop/hello/test-library/target/scala-2.11/test-library-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/<my-name>/.m2/repository/com/example/test-library/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-library-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /tmp/mvninstall9208544268925838468.pom to /home/<my-name>/.m2/repository/com/example/test-library/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/test-library-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`... I used `sbt make-pom` to generate the POM file.

Comment: Hmm, Ok. Another thing to check - is your `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` uberjar? If not, you probably would have to add test-library manually to the class path.

Comment: It should be.  That's why I'm using `sbt-assembly` to build the Jar, so that I can package all of the dependencies together.  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: Not quite - your config suggests that `test-library` is an uberjar with all dependencies packed in. But `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT` relies on `test-library` and it would have to be an uberjar itself to contain all the dependencies without the need to specify classpath either in manifest file or in command line.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok That worked.  I had to include the Maven-Shade-Plugin and the Maven-Jar-Plugin in my project's POM.XML.  The next time I packaged the JAR, it ran and printed "Hello!!!" to the screen.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `test-library` was uberjar, but `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` not. After building the latter as uberjar as well problem was solved.